# Axis Intervals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set the intervals for the x-axis in the following graph.

[image]

I would like to have a break every second year. However, when I try to change the scale_x_continuous variable in the following code to go from 2000.5 to 2020.5 every second year, nothing is happening.

```
p<-ggplot(graphset.melt,  aes(x=time,  y=value)) + 
geom_ribbon(data=graphset, aes(x=time, y=Fitted, ymin=Fitted-dev,  ymax=Fitted + dev), alpha=.2,  fill=error.ribbon) +
geom_line(aes(colour=variable),size=line.size) +
geom_vline(x=max(actual_values$time),  lty=2) +
xlab('Time') + ylab('Engine Size [cc]')+ 
theme_bw() + 
opts(legend.position=c(0.1,0.85)) + scale_colour_hue('')

p = p + theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank() , # remove the vertical grid lines
             panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
p = p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2000.5, 2020.5))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2000.5,2020.5,by=2))

plot(p)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's impossible to answer to your question because your problem isn't reproducible - we don't have your data `graphset.melt` and `graphset`.

Comment: Read http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_date.html